# What does make[number] mean in make V=s?

Tags: compiling, make, gnu-make

When I enable `make V=s` to read the full log of `make`. I always see `make[numer]` in the log.
e.g:

```
datle@debian:~/workspace/cpx/trunk$ make
rm -rf openwrt/tmp
cp config/defaut.config openwrt/.config
cd openwrt && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
Collecting package info: done
Collecting target info: done
Checking 'working-make'... ok.
Checking 'case-sensitive-fs'... ok.
Checking 'getopt'... ok.
Checking 'fileutils'... ok.
Checking 'working-gcc'... ok.
Checking 'working-g++'... ok.
Checking 'ncurses'... ok.
Checking 'zlib'... ok.
Checking 'gawk'... ok.
Checking 'unzip'... ok.
Checking 'bzip2'... ok.
Checking 'patch'... ok.
Checking 'perl'... ok.
Checking 'python'... ok.
Checking 'wget'... ok.
Checking 'git'... ok.
Checking 'gnutar'... ok.
Checking 'svn'... ok.
Checking 'gnu-find'... ok.
Checking 'getopt-extended'... ok.
Checking 'non-root'... ok.
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
Checking 'openssl'... ok.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/datle/workspace/cpx/trunk/openwrt'
WARNING: your configuration is out of sync. Please run make menuconfig, oldconfig or defconfig!
 make[2] world
 make[3] target/compile
 make[4] -C target/linux compile
 make[3] package/cleanup
 make[3] package/compile
 make[4] -C package/toolchain compile
 make[4] -C package/wireless-tools compile
```

I read the [make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) but I didn't find any detail about this.

Comment: Can you please post the verbatim lines, and not pseudo recreations? The output matters in this case. Off the top of my head, I'd say they're probably error numbers.

Comment: Nope, those are not error numbers. I'm afraid I can shed no light on the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers is represent for `makelevel`, which let us know how sub-make relates to top-level `make`.

This is the recursive use of make, see more details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html).

Digging into `make` source code, you can see something clearer.

In `main.c`:

```
/* Value of the MAKELEVEL variable at startup (or 0).  */                       

unsigned int makelevel;
```

and then:

```
/* Figure out the level of recursion.  */                                     
  {                                                                             
    struct variable *v = lookup_variable (STRING_SIZE_TUPLE (MAKELEVEL_NAME));  
    if (v && v->value[0] != '\0' && v->value[0] != '-')                         
      makelevel = (unsigned int) atoi (v->value);                               
    else                                                                        
      makelevel = 0;                                                            
  }
```

In `output.c`:

```
/* Use entire sentences to give the translators a fighting chance.  */        
  if (makelevel == 0)                                                           
    if (starting_directory == 0)                                                
      if (entering)                                                             
        fmt = _("%s: Entering an unknown directory\n");                         
      else                                                                      
        fmt = _("%s: Leaving an unknown directory\n");                          
    else                                                                        
      if (entering)                                                             
        fmt = _("%s: Entering directory '%s'\n");                               
      else                                                                      
        fmt = _("%s: Leaving directory '%s'\n");                                
  else
```

And format the output before printing:

```
if (makelevel == 0)                                                           
    if (starting_directory == 0)                                                
      sprintf (p, fmt , program);                                               
    else                                                                        
      sprintf (p, fmt, program, starting_directory);                            
  else if (starting_directory == 0)                                             
    sprintf (p, fmt, program, makelevel);                                       
  else                                                                          
    sprintf (p, fmt, program, makelevel, starting_directory);                   

  _outputs (NULL, 0, buf);
```

**Note**

- Source [make](https://github.com/mturk/gnumake)